# Change localhost links when deploying Angular app on a shared web hosting server

Tags: java, angular, rest, hosting, web-deployment

When I run my app localy I had a link for redirecting something like `http://localhost:4200/home` from Java RESTful service to Angular app. It worked.

Now when I trying to deploy it on a shared web hosting I changed it with a variable like `appProperties.getUrlhome()`, where in `application.properties` I have `app.properties.urlhome=http://my-domain.com:4200/home`. It does not work. How the link should look like now? Should I change the port or something?

Comment: Is the server's HTTP port not 80? So it would be something like `http://my-domain.com/home`. Right?

Comment: Tried that. Got 404

Comment: Does your web application (Angula build) have the /home route registered in AppRouting? Another thing... When accessing your application through the address http://my-domain.com, do you get a positive result? Is she really on the air?

Comment: The behavior when accessing the default address would redirect to index, does this work? If yes, there is a problem in the routing of the web application, specifically in the /home path.

Comment: my-domain.com redirects to spring boot security login page wich is hosted on separeted VPS running rest service. After succesful login it should go to my shaared hosting site, where Angular app is. The thing is when localy testing these both servers are localhost. One is on port 8080 and other is on 4200. But in production, I have two server, my-rest-service-vps:8080/api/login wich then should redirect to my-domain.com/home. It works localy, but not when site is hosted. Going to my-domain.com redirects to my-rest-service-vps and after login it redicects back to my-domain/home wich givs 404

Comment: Why login to the page provided by Spring-Security? Login should be done via a post request from your webapp (a frontend login page) to ...:8080/auth, once logged in and processed the post return at ...:8080/auth your own webapp would redirect /home. The error pointed out after the first comment is 404 (Not Found) that is, there is no such path in the webapp; With the removal (commenting) of the authentication layer, are you able to access your webapp? If there is no problem there in the host or port.

Comment: if http://localhost:4200/home is accessible normally then http://my-domain/home should work if the port and dns (or ip) are valid.